# ¿Cómo funciona la llamada en este caso de función recursiva?

Tags: java, quicksort, stack

hice una función de quicksort (de manera recursiva), en donde se retorna así:

```
return concatenar(quicksort(izquierda), pivot, quicksort(derecha));
```

la función concatenar es otra que cree para el quicksort. En donde se une unArrayList + unEntero + otroArrayList.

Mi duda es:
- ¿la funcion concatenar es la primera que se llama en el stack?
- Luego, ¿cual función quicksort queda en el top del stack, la de "quicksort(izquierda)" ó la de "quicksort(derecha)"?
- ¿se puede abrir memoria en el stack para dos funciones a la vez?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

La ejecución sucede primero en los parámetros de entrada, ya que para que la función se pueda ejecutar necesita que se hayan resuelto las funciones de sus parámetros, por lo que a la final el orden de ejecución será.

1. `quicksort(izquierda)`
2. `quicksort(derecha)`
3. `concatenar`